# How to pass "dynamic" objects to mocked methods in MOQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

i have a problem with the Moq framework. I try to setup a method which has an `dynamic` argument.

```cs
public class Cls
{
  public string Method(dynamic obj)
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

When i try to mock this type

```cs
var mockCls = new Mock<Cls>();
mockCls .Setup(_ => _.Method(It.IsAny<object>())).Returns("Test");
```

but i`ve got an exception running the test

```
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: _ => _.Method(It.IsAny<object>())
Non-overridable members (here: Cls.Method) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Best regards
Daniel

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is and it has nothing to do with `dynamic`. A method to mock must be `virtual` (and is typically an interface method).

Comment: You can't mock non-virtual members with _constrained_ frameworks like Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy. However, it can be done using _unconstrained_ mocking tools such as TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes (all three are paid), or free alternatives: Prig, Ionad.Fody, AutoFake, Unmockable, Harmony, MethodRedirect, Pose, Shimmy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the method `virtual` in `Cls`

```
public class Cls
{
  public virtual string Method(dynamic obj)
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could use an interface like so:

```
public interface IMethodUser
{
    string Method(dynamic obj);
}

public class Cls : IMethodUser
{
  public string Method(dynamic obj)
  {
    // do something
  }
}

var mockMethodUser = new Mock<IMethodUser>();
mockMethodUser.Setup(x => x.Method(It.IsAny<object>())).Returns("Test");
```

Comment: is there a way without change the signature?

Comment: You could use an interface, will update the answer